# Uninterrupted background music across all activities in Android Studio game

Tags: java, android-studio, game-development

I am currently working on a game in Android Studio and am having issues with implementing a constant soundtrack across all activities. The way I want it to work is that when the app is started up, an audio file will begin playing and looping and will continue looping throughout all activities, and essentially never end (or restarted when changing activities). At some point I would also add a mute/silent button as well. My question really is, how can I create a class for this sound file to play on repeat upon booting the app and also continue without interruption when changing activities. As it currently stands I have a few lines declaring a Mediaplayer object and setting it to loop and playing it, within each activity.. I realize this is not an efficient implementation but I am brand new to Android Studio and still figuring this out.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this tutorial:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/258176/Adding-Background-Music-to-Android-App

And start the Music Service in your MainActivity, if there are still any issues, then let me know.

Comment: I'm currently trying to use the snippets of code you suggested. I am still having some issues with getting this to work. I've made a java class for the first code given, the MusicService class, in my project view it is under java, but not in the folder of all other java codes in the game. I tried implementing the second code given into the first run javacode of the game and cannot seem to get this working still. I'm sorry that I'm not very good at explaining the scenario. Thanks again for the help though..